# Simple service won't bind : bindService return false, service connection never triggered

Tags: java, android, service, android-service, android-service-binding

This is my first time using Service in Android and my service won't bind.

The Service code :

```
package mackosoft.almightymessage;
public final class MainService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "Main Service";
    private final IBinder binder = new MainServiceBinder();

    @Override
    public final void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service created");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public final int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public final void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service created");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service binded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return this.binder;
    }

public final class MainServiceBinder extends Binder {
        final MainService getService() {
            return MainService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest file :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mackosoft.almightymessage" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MainService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>

</Application
</manifest>
```

And finally the part in MainActivity where I try to bind the service :

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected final void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.MainServiceBinder.class);
        final boolean status = bindService(intent, this.connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Service binded ? " + status);
    }

 private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service connected !");
            service = ((MainService.MainServiceBinder) iBinder).getService(); // service is a private member of MainActivity
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service disconnected !");
        }
    };
}
```

Running the application, Logcat shows :

`mackosoft.almightymessage D/MainActivity﹕ Service binded ? false`

And Service Connection is NEVER triggered !

I tried multiple solution :

1. Moving the binding call to a `Button.onClick()` and using `getApplicationContext()`
2. Using directly `getApplicationContext()`
3. In the Manifest, changed -> `android:name="mackosoft.almightymessage.MainService"`
4. Changed also the `Intent`-> `final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainService.MainServiceBinder.class);`
5. Also tried to add `this.startService(intent)` and with `this.getApplicationContext()`

All of the above fail and no error in the logs !

I have no luck at all.

Test device : Samsung Galaxy Note 3 running Cyanogen Mode 12.1 (Android 5.1)

Android Studio 1.2.1.1 (stable)

Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.MainServiceBinder.class);
```

Should be

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainService.class);
```

See the [example provided in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for further info

Comment: How silly of me... I thank you for your sharp eye. I just don't get why I did not see it... I was reading multiple answers on Stackoverflow as well as a good handfull tutorials ... and I stood there wondering why I did not work. I was driving me nuts ! So once again, thank you !